# How to return the fields defined by the interface not by the mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, tsoa

How can I return "id" insted of "_id" and without "__v" to the client with express, mongoose and TypeScript?

**My code below:**

Interface

```
export default interface Domain {
  name: string;
  objects: DomainObject[]
}
```

Creation Interface

```
export default interface DomainCreate {
    name: string
}
```

Mongoose Model

```
const DomainSchema = new Schema<Domain>({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
});

const DomainModel = mongoose.model<Domain>("Domain", DomainSchema);
export { DomainModel, DomainSchema };
```

Service

```
export default class DomainService {
  public async create(params: DomainCreate): Promise<Domain> {
    const domainModel = new DomainModel<Domain>({name: params.name, objects: []});
    const domainCreated = await domainModel.save().then();
    return domainCreated;
  }
}
```

Controller (POST)

```
  @Post()
  @SuccessResponse("201", "Created")
  @Response<ValidateErrorJSON>(422, "Validation Failed")
  @Response<UnauthorizedErrorJson>(401, "Unauthorized")
  @Security("api_key")
  public async createDomain(@Body() requestBody: DomainCreate): Promise<Domain> {
    const createdDomain = await new DomainService().create(requestBody);
    if (createdDomain) this.setStatus(201);
    else this.setStatus(500);
    return createdDomain;
  }
```

Test:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/domains
{
  "name": "D1"
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "name": "D1",
  "_id": "6291e582ade3b0f8be6921dd",
  "__v": 0
}
```

**Expected response:**

```
{
  "name": "D1",
  "id": "6291e582ade3b0f8be6921dd"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be different ways to do it, but you can choose [normalize-mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-mongoose). It will remove `_id`, `__v` and gives you `id`;

So, in your schema you can add this plugin like this:

```
import normalize from 'normalize-mongoose';

const DomainSchema = new Schema<Domain>({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
});

DomainSchema.plugin(normalize);

const DomainModel = mongoose.model<Domain>("Domain", DomainSchema);
export { DomainModel, DomainSchema };
```

Comment: It looks like a perfect solution. Unfortunatelly, I'm getting this error when using normalize-mongoose. I've added "type": "module" to the package.json but it caused onother errors in my project. Is there any easy way to solve the problem without adding "type": "module"? 
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Tests\test1\node_modules\normalize-mongoose\index.js from C:\Tests\test1\build\src\domain\domainModel.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Tests\test1\build\src\domain\domainModel.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

Comment: Which node version are you using? Just change import statement to require. It will work on latest node.ks

Comment: var normalize = require('normalize-mongoose');
...
DomainSchema.plugin(normalize);

The same error :(
Node vesrion: v16.14.0

Comment: You should add "type":"module" in package.json. Check how to use import in node.js.